# Referencing Image assests without using String

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to know if what I'm doing is right or I'm just writing unnecessary code. I want to achieve two things. The first and most important thing is I want to replace the way strings are referenced in `Image.asset(string)` to avoid the mistake of missing a word, and so I created the `ImageAssetManager` class below:

```
class ImageAssetManager {
static const _prefixID = 'assets/images';

static const _homeImages = <String, String>{

    'home_1': '$_prefixID/home_1.jpg',
    'home_2': '$_prefixID/home_2.jpg',
    'home_3': '$_prefixID/home_3.jpg',
    'home_4': '$_prefixID/home_4.jpg',
    'home_5': '$_prefixID/home_5.jpg',
    'home_6': '$_prefixID/home_6.jpg',
  };

  static final home_1 = Image.asset(_homeImages['home_1'] as String);
  static final home_2 = Image.asset(_homeImages['home_2'] as String);
  static final home_3 = Image.asset(_homeImages['home_3'] as String);
  static final home_4 = Image.asset(_homeImages['home_4'] as String);
  static final home_5 = Image.asset(_homeImages['home_5'] as String);
  static final home_6 = Image.asset(_homeImages['home_6'] as String);

}
```

and the second thing I want to achieve is to cache the images using `precacheImage()`, and so I added this method to the class;

```
static void preLoadImageAssets(BuildContext context) {
        for (var key in _homeImages.keys) {
          if (key == 'home_3') {
            continue;
          }
          precacheImage(Image.asset('${_homeImages[key]}').image, context);
        }
      }
```

and the conditional statement in the for-loop was just to purposely omit one image so I can compare the load time . I called the `ImageAssetManager.preLoadImageAssets(context)` method in the `didChangeDependencies()` method in a `Stateful Widget`...and so i have this in the build method of the stateful widget:

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: ImageAssetManager.home_1),
            Expanded(child: ImageAssetManager.home_2),
            Expanded(child: ImageAssetManager.home_3),
            Expanded(child: ImageAssetManager.home_4),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

After all this, I did not see the effect of using `precacheImage()`, maybe because I did not use it right(I dont't really know)

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine. Maybe you’re not seeing a difference because your images are small in size.

Alternatively there is this package for asset generation to lighten some of the load:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_asset_generator

Comment: Thank you. I assumed everyone was on a Christmas break

Comment: How do you know we're not? :)